# Handling space-between in flatlist when numColumns is 3

Tags: react-native, flexbox, flatlist

I have numColumns 3 in flatlist.
I want my flatlist to be shown as

```
ooo
oo
```

not

```
ooo
o o
```

If my data is data%3==2

Here is my code

```
columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent:'space-between'}}
```

And my component's width is (width-6)/3 so it needs 3 px space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is running over a state then you can try the following

```
columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent: data%3 == 2 ? 'flex-start' : 'space-between'}}
```

Comment: what if my components needs at least 3 px spaces between my product

Comment: Can you provide us with some more code, then I can help you with your question. Normally you give the items a marginRight, except the last item in the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty object add the end of data array like this and renderItem accordingly. Just make the extra item invisible.

```
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    if (!item.empty) {
      return <YourComponent />;
    } else {
      return <View style={styles.invisible} />;
    }
  };
```

and

```
  <FlatList
    data={data.length % 3 === 2 ? [...data, { empty: true }] : data }
    renderItem={renderItem}
  />
```